# Implementing an extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, extension-methods

I have this code:

```
 namespace Zinc.Web.Extensions.DataModel.Training
 {
   public static class TrainingModuleProgressStateDataModelExtentions
   { 
      public static string GetHintText(String aString)
      {

         //must still make up astring here
         return aString;
       }
   }
 }

 namespace Zinc.DataModels.Training
 {
    public class TrainingModuleProgressStateDataModel
    {
      public IEnumerable<UserTrainingPointsDataModel> UserTrainingPoints { get; set; }
    }
  }

  public class UserTrainingPointsDataModel
  {
    public virtual int InteractionType { get; set; }
    public virtual int Points { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string IncentiveTrainingModuleOptionName { get; set; }
  }
```

in my repository i add to UserTrainingPoints:

```
 string RawPoints = row["RawPoints"].ToString();
 string[] rawPoints = RawPoints.Split(new char[] { '|' });
 List<UserTrainingPointsDataModel> points = new List<UserTrainingPointsDataModel>();

 foreach (var RawPoint in rawPoints)
 {
   string[] entry = RawPoint.Split(new char[] { ',' });
   var point = new UserTrainingPointsDataModel();
   point.Name = entry[0];
   point.Points = Convert.ToInt32(entry[1]);
   point.InteractionType = Convert.ToInt32(entry[2]);
   point.IncentiveTrainingModuleOptionName = entry[3];
   points.Add(point);  

 }
 trainingModuleProgressState.UserTrainingPoints = points;
 data.Add(trainingModuleProgressState);
```

in my view i need to call the extension method which will take values in UserTrainingPoints to make up a string which i will then show in a tooltip.

my question is how do i implement the extension method so i can call it in my view?

my view code:

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Zinc.Models.Training.TrainingModuleProgressStateDataModelResults>" %>
 <%@ Import namespace="Zinc.Web.Extensions.DataModel.Training" %> //added this

  <% if (module.HasAssessment)
  { %>
     <div class="<%: moduleStateClass %>">&nbsp;</div>
     <div class="<%: moduleScoreClass %>"><%: module.ModuleScore %>%</div>
     <% Zinc.Web.Extensions.DataModel.Training.TrainingModuleProgressStateDataModelExtentions.GetHintText(module.UserTrainingPoints); %>  //still not correct here
```

Comment: The code you showed us doesn't contain any extension methods. What method do you want to be an extension method? And for which type?

Comment: The class name suggests `TrainingModuleProgressStateDataModelExtentions.GetHintText` should be an extension method, but it takes as its only parameter a string. That doesn't seem right. Try getting it working without making it an extension method first, and convert it to an extension method afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `UserTrainingPoints` is a `IEnumerable<UserTrainingPointsDataModel>` I would think your extension method signature should be

```
public static string GetHintText(this IEnumerable<UserTrainingPointsDataModel> points)
{
    string aString;
    //must still make up astring here
    return aString;
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```
module.UserTrainingPoints.GetHintText();
```

Comment: thanks but I should pass something in module.UserTrainingPoints.GetHintText() and not sure what?

Comment: Technically you are passing in the `module.UserTrainingPoints` to the method.

Comment: get an error in the view stating that Zinc.Models.Training.TrainingModuleProgressStateDataModelResults does not contain a definition for GetHintText? i have this in my view: <%@ using  Zinc.Web.Extensions.DataModel.Training %>?

Comment: What happens if you change it to `TrainingModuleProgressStateDataModelExtentions.GetHintText(module.UserTrainingPoints)`

Comment: It says i have "some invalid arguments, best overload method for... "

Comment: What's your current signature for the `GetHintText` method.

Comment: public static string GetHintText(List<UserTrainingPointsDataModel> HintTextString) because module.UserTrainingPoints is a list of type UserTrainingPointsDataModel

Comment: Well the error seems to indicate that `module.UserTrainingPoints` is not a list of `UserTrainingPointsDataModel`.  If you can get it to work though all you need is to add `this` before the param to make it an extension method.

Comment: please see OP: it is a list of UserTrainingPointsDataModel the middle code section :)

Comment: Actually your code has `UserTrainingPoints` defined as `IEnumerable<UserTrainingPointsDataModel>`.  Just change the signature of your method to `GetHintText(this IEnumerable<UserTrainingPointsDataModel> points)` and it should work.

Comment: aaaah thanks! yes that is the problem it should be of type IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

Accessing extension methods is done the same way as you normally would do it.
You should, however, take care that you make a reference to the namespace the extension was added to, using the @using keyword.

Comment: thanks, should i add this to my view? <%@ using  Zinc.Web.Extensions.DataModel.Training %>